# google colab /bin/bash: 'gdrive/My Drive/path/myfile : Permission denied

Tags: python, bash, permissions, file-permissions, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a file (an executable) in google colab  I mounted the drive and everything is ok however whenever i try to run it using :

`!  'gdrive/My Drive/path/myfile'`

I get this output of the cell:

`/bin/bash: 'gdrive/My Drive/path/myfile : Permission denied`

any ideas how to overcome the permissions?

Comment: What kind of file is it? There might be another way to run it, no?

Comment: no extension -binary executable file-

Comment: i actually found that the file wasn't executable so i modified it with `chmod`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you first need to permit that file/folder as:
    *chmod 755 file_name*

Comment: Thanks, I almost have believed it that they restricted 'ngrok', when I have used it for logs forwarding

Comment: can someone explain how to give the executable permission to a specific folder? I mean the code

Comment: For my own notes, I had to first change current directory to where my executable (blender) was using `cd` command and then use `!chmod 755 blender` (note the exclamation) to get rid of permission denied error.